# Spectrum of an operator $\sigma(L)$

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

How can I find $\sigma(L)$,  $\sigma_{p}(L)$ ,  $\sigma_{c}(L)$ i ,  $\sigma_{r}(L)$ for operator $L(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots)=(x_{2},\frac{1}{2}x_{3},\frac{1}{3}x_{4},\ldots)$ ?

Comment: Your thoughts? $\ $

Comment: We have $\sigma(L)=\mathbb{C} \setminus \rho(L)$. 
$$\big(L-\lambda I\big)x=\big(L-\lambda I\big)\big(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}, \ldots \big)=Lx-\lambda x=$$
$$\big(x_{2},\frac{1}{2}x_{3},\frac{1}{3}x_{4},\ldots\big)-\big(\lambda x_{1},\lambda x_{2},\lambda x_{3},\ldots\big)=(x_{2}-\lambda x_{1},\frac{1}{2}x_{3}-\lambda x_{2},\frac{1}{3}x_{4}-\lambda x_{3},\ldots)$$ ...next, I don't have idea. Do you have anything similary ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, show that $\|L\|=1$. So $\sigma(L)$ is inside the closed unit disk $\overline{\mathbb D}$.

From what you wrote in your comment, you easily get that if $(L-\lambda I)x=0$, then 
$$
x_{k+1}=k\lambda^k. 
$$
The element $(k\lambda^k)_k$ is in $\ell^2(\mathbb N)$ if and only if $|\lambda|<1$. It follows that $$\sigma(L)=\overline{\mathbb D}, \ \ \ \sigma_p(L)=\mathbb D. $$ For any $\lambda\in\mathbb D$, it is easy to check that the range of $L-\lambda I$ contains each element in the canonical basis, so it is dense. Thus
$$
\sigma_c(L)=\mathbb T,\ \ \ \ \sigma_r(L)=\varnothing. 
$$

Comment: Thank you 

Comment: Please upvote, and eventually accept, if you find this useful (not only my answer, but others on the site, too).

Comment: Ok. I did. What is T in equality $\sigma_{c}(L)=T ?

Comment: The unit circle.